# Way To Call Through Dongle in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: mobile-broadband

I am living in Sri Lanka and cheapest way for access internet is through pre-paid mobile broadband here. In order to recharge pre-paid account we need to remove the SIM card from from the dongle and connect to a phone. After recharge then again need to connect the SIM to the dongle. To avoid this difficulties it is better if we can dial through the dongle for recharge with a software. In some other OS, we can do this with Mobile Partner software. But in Ubuntu, the version supported is unable to make calls/ dial.

If someone can help to find a solution, it would be a great help.

Comment: Could you include what exact dongle you have there? Please use `lsusb` in the terminal to identify it. Also, is it a voice call you need to do or is it a 'special' command to the network through the dialer on a phone? (Usually starts with `*`)

Comment: lsusb result :Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E169/E620/E800 HSDPA Modem . SMS reloading is more difficult. Need to dial a short code and follow voice instructions to reload and activate internet packages.

Comment: This is not a commercial support site. It's a community support page here. Posting comments in ALL CAPS is considered rude and not very constructive. If you need urgent help on this you'll have to consult an expert or ask Canonical. Also, your `lsusb` output is not complete. The numeric product/vendor ID is missing. Please **edit** your question to include more information rather than posting comments.

Comment: lsusb RESULT.....  Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub      
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub       
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub    
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub     
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 10f1:1a34 Importek      
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 12d1:1001 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E169/E620/E800 HSDPA Modem

Comment: bro just recharge it online only net packs , internet data will be refilled automatically ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using [Modem Manager GUI](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/modem-manager-gui/) instead of mobile partner for linux

**Install Modem Manager GUI in ubuntu 12.04 and above**

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:linuxonly/modem+manager+gui
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install modem-manager-gui
```

**Pros**

1. View device information: Operator name, Mode, IMEI, IMSI, Signal level.
2. Send and receive SMS messages with long massages concatenation and store messages in database
3. Send USSD requests and read answers in GSM7 and UCS2 formats converted to system UTF8 charset.
4. Scan available mobile networks
   5.It integrates with the ubuntu messaging indicator menu

**Cons**

1. no voice support

Comment: Exellent ! @ Prasad . Do you have a solution even for [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/312523/way-to-resolve-problem-with-gadmei-tv-tuner) ?

Comment: I couldn't find Pros and Cons anywhere. How to find ?

Comment: This modem-manager not supported for 13.04

Comment: @user123456 i've edited the answer.