# Way To Resolve Problem With GADMEI TV Tuner

Tags: software-recommendation, tv-tuner

I am having a Gadmei UTV382e USB TV tuner. In Sri Lanka. mostly used TV tuner is Gadmei. Other brands are rarely found. In this TV tuner chip, there isn't a driver for Linux.

Can it be driven from a other application ?

Is there any method to overcome this problem ?

Here is `lsusb` output :

```
dumindumahawela@dumindumahawela:~$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 10f1:1a34 Importek 
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 1f71:3306  
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 12d1:1001 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E169/E620/E800 HSDPA Modem
```

The device with no name is that TV tuner.

Comment: Try this.I am unable to test it out cuz I don't have a TV Tuner with me, http://askubuntu.com/questions/123925/television-on-linux-with-tv-tuner-how-can-i-find-a-way-to-use-it

Comment: That Question and the answers are seems to be helpful. I will try.