# No Sounds in Call With Wammu

Tags: sound, gammu

I am in Ubuntu 13.04 amd64 system.

I installed Wammu with Gammu. When I am trying to call with Wammu,through Huawei E169 3G USB Modem, there is no sounds in Wammu (Dial tone or call sounds).

But rings are going on in the Remote connection. It also doesn't get sounds from incomming (from computer).

I was able to get calls from this device with the application, Mobile Parner previously in Windows. So it supports calls.

This also not works with Mobile Partner in Ubuntu. I asked this question also : [Way To Call Through Dongle in Ubuntu 13.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/312516/way-to-call-through-dongle-in-ubuntu-13-04/348310#348310)

There is Log report.

```
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:46: [Gammu            - 1.33.0 built 15:30:05 Jul 12 2013 using GCC 4.7]
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:46: [Connection       - "at19200"]
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:46: [Connection index - 0]
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:46: [Model type       - ""]
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:46: [Device           - "/dev/ttyUSB0"]
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:46: [Running on       - Linux, kernel 3.8.0-31-generic (#46-Ubuntu SMP Tue Sep 10 20:03:44 UTC 2013)]
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:46: Serial device: DTR is up, RTS is up, CAR is up, CTS is up
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:46: Setting speed to 19200
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:46: [Module           - "auto"]
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:46: Escaping SMS mode
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:46: SENDING frametype 0x00/length 0x02/2
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:46: 1B |0D                                                          ..              
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:46: Sending simple AT command to wake up some devices
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:46: SENDING frametype 0x00/length 0x03/3
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:46: 41A|54T|0D                                                      AT.             
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:47: 1 "AT"
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:47: 2 "OK"
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:47: Checking line: OK
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:47: AT reply state: 1
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:47: RECEIVED frametype 0x00/length 0x09/9
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:47: 41A|54T|0D |0D |0A |4FO|4BK|0D |0A                              AT...OK..       
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:48: Enabling echo
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:48: SENDING frametype 0x00/length 0x05/5
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:48: 41A|54T|45E|311|0D                                              ATE1.           
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:48: 1 "ATE1"
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:48: 2 "OK"
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:48: Checking line: OK
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:48: AT reply state: 1
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:48: RECEIVED frametype 0x00/length 0x0B/11
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:48: 41A|54T|45E|311|0D |0D |0A |4FO|4BK|0D |0A                      ATE1...OK..     
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:48: Trying Motorola mode switch
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:48: SENDING frametype 0x00/length 0x0A/10
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:48: 41A|54T|2B+|4DM|4FO|44D|45E|3D=|322|0D                          AT+MODE=2.      
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:48: 1 "AT+MODE=2"
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:48: 2 "COMMAND NOT SUPPORT"
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:48: Checking line: COMMAND NOT SUPPORT
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:48: AT reply state: 3
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:48: RECEIVED frametype 0x00/length 0x21/33
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:48: 41A|54T|2B+|4DM|4FO|44D|45E|3D=|322|0D |0D |0A |43C|4FO|4DM|4DM AT+MODE=2...COMM
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:48: 41A|4EN|44D|20 |4EN|4FO|54T|20 |53S|55U|50P|50P|4FO|52R|54T|0D  AND NOT SUPPORT.
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:48: 0A                                                              .               
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:48: Seems not to be supported
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:48: Enabling CME errors
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:48: SENDING frametype 0x00/length 0x0A/10
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:48: 41A|54T|2B+|43C|4DM|45E|45E|3D=|311|0D                          AT+CMEE=1.      
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:49: 1 "AT+CMEE=1"
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:49: 2 "OK"
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:49: Checking line: OK
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:49: AT reply state: 1
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:49: RECEIVED frametype 0x00/length 0x10/16
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:49: 41A|54T|2B+|43C|4DM|45E|45E|3D=|311|0D |0D |0A |4FO|4BK|0D |0A  AT+CMEE=1...OK..
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:49: SENDING frametype 0x00/length 0x09/9
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:49: 41A|54T|2B+|43C|53S|43C|53S|3F?|0D                              AT+CSCS?.       
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:49: 1 "AT+CSCS?"
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:49: 2 "+CSCS: "UCS2""
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:49: 3 "OK"
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:49: Checking line: OK
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:49: AT reply state: 1
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:49: RECEIVED frametype 0x00/length 0x20/32
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:49: 41A|54T|2B+|43C|53S|43C|53S|3F?|0D |0D |0A |2B+|43C|53S|43C|53S AT+CSCS?...+CSCS
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:49: 3A:|20 |22"|55U|43C|53S|322|22"|0D |0A |0D |0A |4FO|4BK|0D |0A  : "UCS2"....OK..
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:49: SENDING frametype 0x00/length 0x08/8
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:49: 41A|54T|2B+|43C|47G|4DM|49I|0D                                  AT+CGMI.        
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:50: 1 "AT+CGMI"
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:50: 2 "huawei"
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:50: 3 "OK"
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:50: Checking line: OK
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:50: AT reply state: 1
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:50: RECEIVED frametype 0x00/length 0x18/24
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:50: 41A|54T|2B+|43C|47G|4DM|49I|0D |0D |0A |68h|75u|61a|77w|65e|69i AT+CGMI...huawei
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:50: 0D |0A |0D |0A |4FO|4BK|0D |0A                                  ....OK..        
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:50: Manufacturer info received
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:50: [Manufacturer: Huawei]
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:50: SENDING frametype 0x00/length 0x0A/10
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:50: 41A|54T|2B+|43C|53S|43C|53S|3D=|3F?|0D                          AT+CSCS=?.      
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:50: 1 "AT+CSCS=?"
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:50: 2 "+CSCS: ("IRA","GSM","UCS2")"
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:50: 3 "OK"
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:50: Checking line: OK
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:50: AT reply state: 1
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:50: RECEIVED frametype 0x00/length 0x2F/47
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:50: 41A|54T|2B+|43C|53S|43C|53S|3D=|3F?|0D |0D |0A |2B+|43C|53S|43C AT+CSCS=?...+CSC
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:50: 53S|3A:|20 |28(|22"|49I|52R|41A|22"|2C,|22"|47G|53S|4DM|22"|2C, S: ("IRA","GSM",
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:50: 22"|55U|43C|53S|322|22"|29)|0D |0A |0D |0A |4FO|4BK|0D |0A      "UCS2")....OK.. 
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:50: Chosen GSM as normal charset
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:50: Chosen UCS2 as unicode charset
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:50: SENDING frametype 0x00/length 0x0E/14
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:50: 41A|54T|2B+|43C|53S|43C|53S|3D=|22"|47G|53S|4DM|22"|0D          AT+CSCS="GSM".  
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:50: 1 "AT+CSCS="GSM""
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:50: 2 "OK"
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:50: Checking line: OK
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:50: AT reply state: 1
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:50: RECEIVED frametype 0x00/length 0x14/20
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:50: 41A|54T|2B+|43C|53S|43C|53S|3D=|22"|47G|53S|4DM|22"|0D |0D |0A  AT+CSCS="GSM"...
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:50: 4FO|4BK|0D |0A                                                  OK..            
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:50: SENDING frametype 0x00/length 0x09/9
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:50: 41A|54T|2B+|43C|53S|43C|53S|3F?|0D                              AT+CSCS?.       
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:51: 1 "AT+CSCS?"
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:51: 2 "+CSCS: "GSM""
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:51: 3 "OK"
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:51: Checking line: OK
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:51: AT reply state: 1
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:51: RECEIVED frametype 0x00/length 0x1F/31
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:51: 41A|54T|2B+|43C|53S|43C|53S|3F?|0D |0D |0A |2B+|43C|53S|43C|53S AT+CSCS?...+CSCS
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:51: 3A:|20 |22"|47G|53S|4DM|22"|0D |0A |0D |0A |4FO|4BK|0D |0A      : "GSM"....OK.. 
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:51: Getting model
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:51: SENDING frametype 0x00/length 0x08/8
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:51: 41A|54T|2B+|43C|47G|4DM|4DM|0D                                  AT+CGMM.        
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:51: 1 "AT+CGMM"
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:51: 2 "E169"
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:51: 3 "OK"
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:51: Checking line: OK
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:51: AT reply state: 1
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:51: RECEIVED frametype 0x00/length 0x16/22
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:51: 41A|54T|2B+|43C|47G|4DM|4DM|0D |0D |0A |45E|311|366|399|0D |0A  AT+CGMM...E169..
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:51: 0D |0A |4FO|4BK|0D |0A                                          ..OK..          
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:51: [Model name: `E169']
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:51: [Model data: `E169']
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:51: [Model data: `E169']
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:51: [Connected model  - "E169"]
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:51: Checking for OBEX support
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:51: SENDING frametype 0x00/length 0x0B/11
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:51: 41A|54T|2B+|43C|50P|52R|4FO|54T|3D=|3F?|0D                      AT+CPROT=?.     
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:51: 1 "AT+CPROT=?"
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:51: 2 "COMMAND NOT SUPPORT"
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:51: Checking line: COMMAND NOT SUPPORT
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:51: AT reply state: 3
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:51: RECEIVED frametype 0x00/length 0x22/34
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:51: 41A|54T|2B+|43C|50P|52R|4FO|54T|3D=|3F?|0D |0D |0A |43C|4FO|4DM AT+CPROT=?...COM
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:51: 4DM|41A|4EN|44D|20 |4EN|4FO|54T|20 |53S|55U|50P|50P|4FO|52R|54T MAND NOT SUPPORT
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:51: 0D |0A                                                          ..              
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:51: Checking for SYNCML/OBEX support
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:51: SENDING frametype 0x00/length 0x0C/12
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:51: 41A|54T|2B+|53S|59Y|4EN|43C|4DM|4CL|3D=|3F?|0D                  AT+SYNCML=?.    
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:51: 1 "AT+SYNCML=?"
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:51: 2 "COMMAND NOT SUPPORT"
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:51: Checking line: COMMAND NOT SUPPORT
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:51: AT reply state: 3
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:51: RECEIVED frametype 0x00/length 0x23/35
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:51: 41A|54T|2B+|53S|59Y|4EN|43C|4DM|4CL|3D=|3F?|0D |0D |0A |43C|4FO AT+SYNCML=?...CO
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:51: 4DM|4DM|41A|4EN|44D|20 |4EN|4FO|54T|20 |53S|55U|50P|50P|4FO|52R MMAND NOT SUPPOR
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:51: 54T|0D |0A                                                      T..             
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:51: Checking for SYNCML/OBEX support
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:51: SENDING frametype 0x00/length 0x0D/13
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:51: 41A|54T|24$|54T|53S|53S|50P|43C|53S|57W|3D=|3F?|0D              AT$TSSPCSW=?.   
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:51: 1 "AT$TSSPCSW=?"
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:51: 2 "COMMAND NOT SUPPORT"
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:51: Checking line: COMMAND NOT SUPPORT
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:51: AT reply state: 3
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:51: RECEIVED frametype 0x00/length 0x24/36
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:51: 41A|54T|24$|54T|53S|53S|50P|43C|53S|57W|3D=|3F?|0D |0D |0A |43C AT$TSSPCSW=?...C
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:51: 4FO|4DM|4DM|41A|4EN|44D|20 |4EN|4FO|54T|20 |53S|55U|50P|50P|4FO OMMAND NOT SUPPO
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:51: 52R|54T|0D |0A                                                  RT..            
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:51: [Module           - "A2D|iPAQ|at|M20|S25|MC35|TC35|C35i|S65|S300|5110|5130|5190|5210|6110|6130|6150|6190|6210|6250|6310|6310i|6510|7110|8210|8250|8290|8310|8390|8850|8855|8890|8910|9110|9210"]
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:51: Escaping SMS mode
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:51: SENDING frametype 0x00/length 0x02/2
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:51: 1B |0D                                                          ..              
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:51: Sending simple AT command to wake up some devices
Tue 2013/10/15 09:55:51: SENDING frametype 0x00/length 0x03/3
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:04: 4BK|0D |0A                                                      K..             
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:04: Checking availability of SBNR
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:04: SENDING frametype 0x00/length 0x0A/10
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:04: 41A|54T|5E^|53S|42B|4EN|52R|3D=|3F?|0D                          AT^SBNR=?.      
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:04: 1 "AT^SBNR=?"
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:04: 2 "COMMAND NOT SUPPORT"
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:04: Checking line: COMMAND NOT SUPPORT
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:04: AT reply state: 3
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:04: RECEIVED frametype 0x00/length 0x21/33
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:04: 41A|54T|5E^|53S|42B|4EN|52R|3D=|3F?|0D |0D |0A |43C|4FO|4DM|4DM AT^SBNR=?...COMM
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:04: 41A|4EN|44D|20 |4EN|4FO|54T|20 |53S|55U|50P|50P|4FO|52R|54T|0D  AND NOT SUPPORT.
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:04: 0A                                                              .               
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:04: Checking availability of SPBR
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:04: SENDING frametype 0x00/length 0x0A/10
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:04: 41A|54T|2B+|53S|50P|42B|52R|3D=|3F?|0D                          AT+SPBR=?.      
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:04: 1 "AT+SPBR=?"
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:04: 2 "COMMAND NOT SUPPORT"
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:04: Checking line: COMMAND NOT SUPPORT
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:04: AT reply state: 3
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:04: RECEIVED frametype 0x00/length 0x21/33
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:04: 41A|54T|2B+|53S|50P|42B|52R|3D=|3F?|0D |0D |0A |43C|4FO|4DM|4DM AT+SPBR=?...COMM
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:04: 41A|4EN|44D|20 |4EN|4FO|54T|20 |53S|55U|50P|50P|4FO|52R|54T|0D  AND NOT SUPPORT.
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:04: 0A                                                              .               
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:04: Checking availability of MPBR
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:04: SENDING frametype 0x00/length 0x0A/10
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:04: 41A|54T|2B+|4DM|50P|42B|52R|3D=|3F?|0D                          AT+MPBR=?.      
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:04: 1 "AT+MPBR=?"
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:04: 2 "COMMAND NOT SUPPORT"
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:04: Checking line: COMMAND NOT SUPPORT
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:04: AT reply state: 3
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:04: RECEIVED frametype 0x00/length 0x21/33
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:04: 41A|54T|2B+|4DM|50P|42B|52R|3D=|3F?|0D |0D |0A |43C|4FO|4DM|4DM AT+MPBR=?...COMM
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:04: 41A|4EN|44D|20 |4EN|4FO|54T|20 |53S|55U|50P|50P|4FO|52R|54T|0D  AND NOT SUPPORT.
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:04: 0A                                                              .               
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:04: SENDING frametype 0x00/length 0x0F/15
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:04: 41A|54T|2B+|43C|53S|43C|53S|3D=|22"|55U|43C|53S|322|22"|0D      AT+CSCS="UCS2". 
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:04: 1 "AT+CSCS="UCS2""
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:04: 2 "OK"
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:04: Checking line: OK
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:04: AT reply state: 1
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:04: RECEIVED frametype 0x00/length 0x15/21
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:04: 41A|54T|2B+|43C|53S|43C|53S|3D=|22"|55U|43C|53S|322|22"|0D |0D  AT+CSCS="UCS2"..
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:04: 0A |4FO|4BK|0D |0A                                              .OK..           
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:04: SENDING frametype 0x00/length 0x09/9
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:04: 41A|54T|2B+|43C|53S|43C|53S|3F?|0D                              AT+CSCS?.       
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:04: 1 "AT+CSCS?"
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:04: 2 "+CSCS: "UCS2""
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:04: 3 "OK"
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:04: Checking line: OK
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:04: AT reply state: 1
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:04: RECEIVED frametype 0x00/length 0x20/32
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:04: 41A|54T|2B+|43C|53S|43C|53S|3F?|0D |0D |0A |2B+|43C|53S|43C|53S AT+CSCS?...+CSCS
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:04: 3A:|20 |22"|55U|43C|53S|322|22"|0D |0A |0D |0A |4FO|4BK|0D |0A  : "UCS2"....OK..
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:04: Getting memory status
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:04: SENDING frametype 0x00/length 0x09/9
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:04: 41A|54T|2B+|43C|50P|42B|53S|3F?|0D                              AT+CPBS?.       
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:04: 1 "AT+CPBS?"
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:04: 2 "+CPBS: "ME",0,100"
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:04: 3 "OK"
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:04: Checking line: OK
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:04: AT reply state: 1
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:04: RECEIVED frametype 0x00/length 0x24/36
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:04: 41A|54T|2B+|43C|50P|42B|53S|3F?|0D |0D |0A |2B+|43C|50P|42B|53S AT+CPBS?...+CPBS
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:04: 3A:|20 |22"|4DM|45E|22"|2C,|300|2C,|311|300|300|0D |0A |0D |0A  : "ME",0,100....
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:04: 4FO|4BK|0D |0A                                                  OK..            
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:04: Memory status received
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:04: Parsing +CPBS: "ME",0,100 with +CPBS: @s, @i, @i
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:04: Grabbed string from reply: "ME" (parsed 4 bytes)
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:04: Parsed generic string "ME"
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:04: Generic string decoded as "ME"
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:04: Parsed int 0
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:04: Parsed int 100
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:04: Getting memory information
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:04: SENDING frametype 0x00/length 0x0A/10
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:04: 41A|54T|2B+|43C|50P|42B|52R|3D=|3F?|0D                          AT+CPBR=?.      
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:04: 1 "AT+CPBR=?"
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:04: 2 "+CPBR: (1-100),24,255"
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:04: 3 "OK"
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:04: Checking line: OK
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:04: AT reply state: 1
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:04: RECEIVED frametype 0x00/length 0x29/41
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:04: 41A|54T|2B+|43C|50P|42B|52R|3D=|3F?|0D |0D |0A |2B+|43C|50P|42B AT+CPBR=?...+CPB
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:04: 52R|3A:|20 |28(|311|2D-|311|300|300|29)|2C,|322|344|2C,|322|355 R: (1-100),24,25
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:04: 355|0D |0A |0D |0A |4FO|4BK|0D |0A                              5....OK..       
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:04: Memory info received
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:04: Parsing +CPBR: (1-100),24,255 with +CPBR: (@i-@i), @i, @i
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:04: Parsed int 1
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:04: Parsed int 100
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:04: Parsed int 24
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:04: Parsed int 255
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:04: Leaving GSM_GetMemoryStatus
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:08: Entering GSM_DialVoice
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:08: Making voice call
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:08: SENDING frametype 0x00/length 0x10/16
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:08: 41A|54T|44D|54T|300|377|377|355|311|355|399|366|355|311|3B;|0D  ATDT0775159651;.
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:08: 1 "ATDT0775159651;"
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:08: 2 "OK"
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:08: Checking line: OK
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:08: AT reply state: 1
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:08: RECEIVED frametype 0x00/length 0x16/22
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:08: 41A|54T|44D|54T|300|377|377|355|311|355|399|366|355|311|3B;|0D  ATDT0775159651;.
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:08: 0D |0A |4FO|4BK|0D |0A                                          ..OK..          
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:08: Dial voice OK
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:08: Leaving GSM_DialVoice
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:08: Entering GSM_GetSignalQuality
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:08: Getting signal quality info
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:08: SENDING frametype 0x00/length 0x07/7
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:08: 41A|54T|2B+|43C|53S|51Q|0D                                      AT+CSQ.         
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:08: 1 "AT+CSQ"
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:08: 2 "+CSQ: 15,99"
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:08: 3 "OK"
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:08: Checking line: OK
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:08: AT reply state: 1
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:08: RECEIVED frametype 0x00/length 0x1C/28
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:08: 41A|54T|2B+|43C|53S|51Q|0D |0D |0A |2B+|43C|53S|51Q|3A:|20 |311 AT+CSQ...+CSQ: 1
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:08: 355|2C,|399|399|0D |0A |0D |0A |4FO|4BK|0D |0A                  5,99....OK..    
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:08: Signal quality info received
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:08: Parsing +CSQ: 15,99 with +CSQ: @i, @i
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:08: Parsed int 15
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:08: Parsed int 99
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:08: Leaving GSM_GetSignalQuality
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:08: Entering GSM_GetBatteryCharge
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:08: Getting battery charge
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:08: SENDING frametype 0x00/length 0x07/7
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:08: 41A|54T|2B+|43C|42B|43C|0D                                      AT+CBC.         
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:08: 1 "AT+CBC"
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:08: 2 "+CBC: 2,0"
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:08: 3 "OK"
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:08: Checking line: OK
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:08: AT reply state: 1
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:08: RECEIVED frametype 0x00/length 0x1A/26
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:08: 41A|54T|2B+|43C|42B|43C|0D |0D |0A |2B+|43C|42B|43C|3A:|20 |322 AT+CBC...+CBC: 2
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:08: 2C,|300|0D |0A |0D |0A |4FO|4BK|0D |0A                          ,0....OK..      
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:08: Battery level received
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:08: Parsing +CBC: 2,0 with +CBC: @i, @i
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:08: Parsed int 2
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:08: Parsed int 0
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:08: Leaving GSM_GetBatteryCharge
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:08: Entering GSM_GetDateTime
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:08: Getting date & time
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:08: SENDING frametype 0x00/length 0x09/9
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:08: 41A|54T|2B+|43C|43C|4CL|4BK|3F?|0D                              AT+CCLK?.       
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:08: 1 "AT+CCLK?"
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:08: 2 "+CCLK: 2013/10/15,09:56:08"
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:08: 3 "OK"
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:08: Checking line: OK
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:08: AT reply state: 1
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:08: RECEIVED frametype 0x00/length 0x2D/45
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:08: 41A|54T|2B+|43C|43C|4CL|4BK|3F?|0D |0D |0A |2B+|43C|43C|4CL|4BK AT+CCLK?...+CCLK
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:08: 3A:|20 |322|300|311|333|2F/|311|300|2F/|311|355|2C,|300|399|3A: : 2013/10/15,09:
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:08: 355|366|3A:|300|388|0D |0A |0D |0A |4FO|4BK|0D |0A              56:08....OK..   
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:08: Parsing +CCLK: 2013/10/15,09:56:08 with +CCLK: @d
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:08: Grabbed string from reply: "2013/10/15" (parsed 10 bytes)
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:08: Grabbed string from reply: "09:56:08" (parsed 8 bytes)
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:08: Parsed string for date "2013/10/15,09:56:08"
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:08: Parsed date: 2013-10-15 9:56:8, TZ 0
Tue 2013/10/15 09:56:08: Leaving GSM_GetDateTime
```

Result of `lsusb` (Last line is the particular device) :

```
dumindumahawela@dumindumahawela:~$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 10f1:1a34 Importek 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 12d1:1001 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E169/E620/E800 HSDPA Modem
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gammu/wammu features are not supported across all hardware

It appears you are trying to make calls,however your device only supports sms not calls http://wammu.eu/phones/huawei/

Comment: But the device supports calls. I got calls with Mobile Partner in Windows earlier. Are you meaning it is not supported only in wammu? Is it so?

Comment: But calls are not supported with gamu/wamu according to the link i posted thus why not working.

Comment: Possibly interesting information: https://github.com/gammu/wammu/issues/29

Maybe the call is made but the audio is not connected.